# What is the correct way to make the browser reach the server alias on a local development machine?

Tags: apache-http-server

Following is the vhost I have configured on my local dev machine:

```
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mytestsite
    ServerAlias x.mytestsite    
    ServerAlias y.mytestsite
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/mytestsite"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/mytestsite/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

1. In the browser when I enter `mytestsite` or `x.mytestsite` or `y.mytestsite` - then it opens it in google search. Is there any way to make the above names point to the virtualhost site?
2. In the browser when I enter `mytestsite/` then it connects to my local site. However, when I enter `x.mytestsite/` or `y.mytestsite/` - then it says web page cannot be found. What is the correct way to make the other 2 sub domains work?
3. As a trial method I modified the hosts file on my computer and added the following lines as shown below; now all 3 (`mytestsite/`, `x.mytestsite/`, `y.mytestsite/`) work. But is modifying the hosts file on the computer a correct to make the subdomains work?

---

```
127.0.0.1 mytestsite
127.0.0.1 x.mytestsite
127.0.0.1 y.mytestsite
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are describing is not in Apache, its with domain resolution (Although Ive not seen 2 server Alias lines on Apache before - aluases are typically on 1 line seperated by spaces.  This may be valid syntax, or maybe just falling back to default)

The correct way to fix this problem is to add the subdomains to the DNS servers zone record.

If you are only ever going to use your local machine to access those addresses, putting it in hosts file is sufficient - but this will only work from machines with the edited hists entries.

Answer (score 0):

As the name implies, the *hosts* file is for host names only. It does not support wildcard entries or anything the like. The syntax is:

```
IP_address canonical_hostname [aliases...]
```

Multiple entries for the same IP address are valid, too.

If you need `example.com`, `a.example.com` and `b.example.com`, you need to explicitly add all three host names to the *hosts* file. So yes, your method is correct.

If you want better ergonomics, consider using a DNS server/forwarder with support for wildcards. *dnsmasq* is one such program. Maybe *systemd-resolved* could do it, too, but I’m not too familiar with it.